# Bluetooth keep disconnecting

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I use ZorinOS, an Ubuntu-based operating system. I have been using this one Bluetooth keyboard for a while now. But this morning it suddenly disconnected for no reason. And it keeps disconnecting after it.

I try to grep the log with `grep "blue" /var/log/syslog`, and get:

```
ov  3 00:17:00 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov  3 00:17:00 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov  3 00:17:25 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Succeeded.
Nov  2 17:17:48 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov  2 17:17:48 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov  2 17:17:49 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov  2 17:17:49 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[593]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' unit='blueman-mechanism.service' requested by ':1.68' (uid=1000 pid=2005 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-mechanism[2118]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[1715]: [session uid=1000 pid=1715] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Applet' unit='blueman-applet.service' requested by ':1.61' (uid=1000 pid=2112 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-tray " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-mechanism[2118]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-mechani[2118]: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[593]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[1715]: [session uid=1000 pid=1715] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Applet'
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[1715]: [session uid=1000 pid=1715] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez.obex' unit='dbus-org.bluez.obex.service' requested by ':1.52' (uid=1000 pid=2005 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[1715]: [session uid=1000 pid=1715] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez.obex'
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-applet[2124]: blueman-applet version 2.1.2 starting
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-applet[2124]: There is an instance already running
Nov  2 17:17:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB systemd[1695]: blueman-applet.service: Succeeded.
Nov  2 17:18:23 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Succeeded.
Nov  2 17:18:40 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[1715]: [session uid=1000 pid=1715] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.52' (uid=1000 pid=2005 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 17:18:42 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Can't get HIDP connection info
Nov  2 17:18:44 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB kernel: [  112.441148] input: Logitech Keyboard K480 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/0005:046D:B330.0006/input/input29
Nov  2 17:18:44 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB upowerd[1878]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/0005:046D:B330.0006/power_supply/hid-34:88:5d:39:97:f5-battery
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Terminating
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Stopping SDP server
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[590]: Exit
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Succeeded.
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: Starting SDP server
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[593]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.178' (uid=0 pid=6506 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov  2 18:15:59 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov  2 18:16:01 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[593]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' unit='blueman-mechanism.service' requested by ':1.68' (uid=1000 pid=2005 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 18:16:01 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-mechanism[6513]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Nov  2 18:16:01 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-mechanism[6513]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Nov  2 18:16:01 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB blueman-mechani[6513]: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Nov  2 18:16:01 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB dbus-daemon[593]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Nov  2 18:16:31 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Succeeded.
Nov  2 18:18:26 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:19:57 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: connect error: Operation already in progress (114)
Nov  2 18:20:05 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: connect error: Host is down (112)
Nov  2 18:24:31 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:26:36 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:28:42 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:30:47 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:32:52 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:34:57 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:37:03 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:39:08 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:41:13 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:43:18 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:45:24 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
Nov  2 18:47:29 lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB bluetoothd[6506]: BT socket not connected
```

It seems like the bt socket got disconnected, but I don't know why.

I connect it and use it for a while and it keep getting disconnected. At first, I thought the keyboard battery is low, but after I changed it, it still getting disconnected. The thing is, this laptop is pretty old, and I already got some bios problem, like it can't gauge the battery power. I assume the bluetooth problem caused by BIOS (?). How to know if the problem caused by my laptop or if the keyboard itself broken?